# 'Cannot Find Module' when using an Image in React

Tags: reactjs, image, webpack, jsx

I am using React and I am running into an issue importing images in a component.  Now I know how to use the import method, which is fine for some things but in this case the image src is part of an array of objects I need to map over.

So let me start with if I do this directly: `<img src={require('../../images/leadinvestigator.jpg')} />`  It works just fine.

However if I do this: `<img src={require(member.image)} />` or `<img src={require(`${member.image}`)} />` I get:

`react-dom.development.js:11340 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../../images/leadinvestigator.jpg'`

and if I do this: `<img src={require({member.image})} />` I get an invalid token error

here is my component code:

```
import React from "react"
import "react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css"
import { Carousel } from 'react-responsive-carousel'
import './styles.css'

const Crew = () => {
  const crewMembers = [
    {
      image: '../../images/leadinvestigator.jpg',
      name: 'Bryant Richards',
      title: 'Lead Investigator',
      quote: 'In the end, it only matters what you believe'
    }
  ]
  return (
    <Carousel
      showArrows={true}
      infiniteLoop={true}
      showThumbs={false}
      showStatus={false}
      autoPlay={true}
      interval={6100}
    >

      {
        crewMembers ? crewMembers.map(member => (
          <div>
            <img src={require('../../images/leadinvestigator.jpg')} />
            <div className="myCarousel">
              <h3>{member.name}</h3>
              <h4>Designer</h4>
              <p>
                It's freeing to be able to catch up on customized news and not be
                distracted by a social media element on the same site
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        )) : null
      }
    </Carousel>
  )
}

export default Crew
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to import your image before put it in the object.

Add on top of your component:

```
import bryantImage from '../../images/leadinvestigator.jpg'
```

and then add this image to your object like that:

```
const crewMembers = [
    {
      image: bryantImage,
      name: 'Bryant Richards',
      title: 'Lead Investigator',
      quote: 'In the end, it only matters what you believe'
    }
  ]
```

Comment: This would work but I would still be curious to see why it doesn't work the more direct method when src in `require` directly works but putting the same source doesn't work if it's a variable.